# Facebook PHP SDK upgrade from 3.2.3 to 4.0.0 on Drupal 6 site

Tags: php, drupal-6, facebook-php-sdk

It seems that the necessary php version for the facebook php 4.0.0 sdk is php5.4 yet drupal 6 sites supports only php 5.3 for now.
Is there a solution for this issue that can use the 4.0.0 sdk without upgrading php to 5.4.

(I'm currently using drupal 6 with php 5.3)

EDIT:
Seems that changing api / graph endpoints to v2.1 did the trick for most of the parts.
will test and see if there are any problems with that implementation.